# How to change background color of ImageView which use setBackgroundResource() from java code?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, border, shapes

I am using the `<shape>` tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
  <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

I have a lot of views I created with the `<shape>` tag in a GridView and I need to change the part that was set here:

```
<solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
```

and set another color, but I don't know how...
I tried to use ImageView.Adapter like this:

```
imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 105));
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(myBackgroundColors[position]);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
```

I set the background color before I call setBackgroundResource() and in XML I use transparent color, but it doesn't work...any ideas?

Comment: Does the background resource get set correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `<shape />` ([Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)) tag in xml the compiled resource is not an imageview; it compiles into a [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html). The `<solid />` tag defines a solid color to fill the defined shape and sets it as `android:color`. Thus, to change this programatically you should use the [setColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColor%28int%29) method.

Comment: It is perfect, man! Now it finally works. Thank you VERY much! :)

Comment: if any snippet then post. look like great